# How to add imports to groovysh on startup?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I'm working on a project where I'd like users to experiment with Java classes on Groovysh. I'd like to make it convenient for them and want to import certain packages by default, when groovysh starts up so that users would not have to re-type the same imports every time they start the shell. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,
igor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the imports to `$HOME/.groovy/groovysh.rc`

Comment: Matthew, thanks, this works, but it requires some configuration on the client box. A more convenient way for me would be a command line option to tell groovysh to load a groovy file. Is this possible? This seems a simple task, but I can't see this in documentation.

thanks,
igor

Comment: Could you change the script to add the relevant configuration to `groovysh.rc` if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: hm, this is an idea, but where can I configure to run a script other than the groovysh.rc?

Answer (score 2):

From http://groovy.codehaus.org/Groovy+Shell:

This script, if it exists, is loaded when the shell starts up:

```
$HOME/.groovy/groovysh.profile
```

This script, if it exists, is loaded when the shell enters interactive mode:

```
$HOME/.groovy/groovysh.rc
```

Edit-line history is stored in this file:

```
$HOME/.groovy/groovysh.history
```