# Groovysh init script

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

I'm looking for a way to have groovysh initialized and then dropped into a regular groovysh interactive session. That is:

- Run some scripts (e.g. imports or anything else)
- Continue running in groovysh as if previous script was typed manually from the start of the session.

Seen this:

- [How to add imports to groovysh on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041907/how-to-add-imports-to-groovysh-on-startup)

but I'd like to be able to do this on a per-application, not per-user level. I.e. different applications usually do not import same things (or initialize in the same way otherwise). Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Since Groovy 2.4 you can use `groovysh -e '... your code here ...'`.

Examples:

```
$ groovysh -e '2+2'
Groovy Shell (2.4.7, JVM: 1.8.0_131)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> 2+2
===> 4
```

If you want to preload a script, use `:load` like so:

```
$ cat preamble.groovy 
def hello(x) {
  "Hello ${x}"
}
println hello("world")

$ groovysh -e ':load preamble.groovy'
Groovy Shell (2.4.7, JVM: 1.8.0_131)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> :load preamble.groovy
===> true
Hello world
===> null
groovy:000> hello('stackoverflow')
===> Hello stackoverflow
```

(in last example I manually typed last line, I could use function `hello` defined in preamble)

Answer (score 0):

Per this post:

- http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/groovy-equivalent-to-python-i-script-py-tp372587p5719768.html

looks like Groovy <= 2.3 doesn't support this and it's going to be present in Groovy 2.4 using this syntax:

```
groovysh -e foo.groovy
```

Comment: Actually it's `groovysh -e ' ... your code here ...'`, so for example `groovysh -e '2+2'`. Unfortunately `groovysh -e 'load "foo.groovy"'` does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Using the [load](http://www.groovy-lang.org/groovysh.html#GroovyShell-load) keyword seems to work:

```
$ cat test.groovy
myStr = "hello World!"
$
$ groovysh
groovy:000> load test.groovy
===> hello World!
groovy:000> println myStr
hello World!
===> null
groovy:000>
```